# How to reach the needed atribute through condition in groupby Pandas&

Tags: python, pandas

Have the following task in jupyter notebook:

> How many women are there in the most crowded class?

Have the following columns in table:

> PassengerId   Survived    Pclass  Name    Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Ticket  Fare    Cabin   Embarked

The 'class' from the task is the 'Pclass' from the table.

Cannot understand how do i solve this.

Have counted number of people for each class:

```
data_by_class = data.groupby(['Pclass'])
data_by_class['Pclass'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Pclass  Pclass
1       1         216
2       2         184
3       3         491
Name: Pclass, dtype: int64
```

I can get the maximum:

`data_by_class['Pclass'].value_counts().max()`

Output:

`491`

How do I connect count to class? It is easy with SQL but do not understand how to do it with Pandas.
Would be grateful if anybody could help with solving the task at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
         'Pclass':[1,2,1,2,2,1],
         'Sex':['male'] + ['female'] * 5
})
```

First is necessary grouping by `Sex` column and add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for convert Series with `MultiIndex` to 3 columns DataFrame:

```
data_by_class = data.groupby('Sex')['Pclass'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
print (data_by_class)
      Sex  Pclass  count
0  female       2      3
1  female       1      2
2    male       1      1
```

Then for maximal values per groups use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = data_by_class.loc[data_by_class.groupby('Sex')['count'].idxmax()]
print (df)
      Sex  Pclass  count
0  female       2      3
2    male       1      1
```

And last if want scalars output convert column to index:

```
df = df.set_index('Sex')
print (df)
        Pclass  count
Sex                  
female       2      3
male         1      1
```

So is possible select by labels by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc['female', 'count'])
3
print (df.loc['female', 'Pclass'])
2
```